# vue-loader: how to use vue-loader v15 in webpack 4 and vue-cli3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I use the latest versions of vue-cli3 *webpack4* and *vue-loader* v15.

I want to configure *vue-loader*, but there is an error:

`Error: [VueLoaderPlugin Error] No matching use for vue-loader is found.
Make sure the rule matching .vue files include vue-loader in its use.`

*vue.config.js*

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");
module.exports = {
    productionSourceMap: false,
    baseUrl: "./",
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader"
            }]
        },
        plugins: [
            new VueLoaderPlugin()
        ]
    }
}
```

*package.js*

```
     "dependencies": {
        "awe-dnd": "^0.3.1",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "iview": "^3.1.5",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.1.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.1",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "eslint": "^5.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.7.1",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "iview-loader": "^1.2.2",
        "less": "^3.9.0",
        "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "vue-cli-plugin-iview": "^1.0.6",
        "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.3.1",
        "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
        "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
        "webpack": "^4.26.1",
        "webpack-chain": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4"
      },
```

I called `console.log` on `vue-loader/plugin.js`.

`rawRules` (line-number 27)

There are 20+ rules.
`/\.vue$/`  matched the second rule.

But the second rule is url-loader?

What do I do?

Comment: I have the same error. Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should put vue-loader on dependencies. Recently i updated my project: vue, vue-loader, webpack...
this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "pack",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --env.prod --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-rc.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.5",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "idle-vue": "^2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^3.0.3",
    "v-offline": "^1.0.10",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.12.2",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-chartkick": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-config": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-embed": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-google-charts": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-popperjs": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.14"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Your webpack.config it seems fine... but just in case, this is my code:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', './App/index.js']
  },
  plugins:[
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
        }
      },

...
```

Comment: maybe you are right,but your `webpack` seems in other file? Use vue-cli ,how to use webpack like this?

Comment: @sdwdjzhy my webpack file is on the root folder

Comment: maybe i need to search the webpack doc .Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same problem and found [this thread](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1438) solved my problem.

Essentially, you do not need to specify the module rules or the loader for vue-loader when using vue-cli to build your app because vue-cli provides vue-loader out of the box.

I do not know why we get the error when we try to specify the module rules, and it is unfortunate that it gives this unhelpful error, but regardless, I hope this helps!